# Как правильно написать replace для нескольких групп захвата?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, replace

Хочу заменить в строке кириллицу на латиницу, благо небольшое разнообразие будет в символах.

- д -> d(дни)
- ч -> h(часы)
- м -> m(минуты)
- с -> s(секунды)

  `key = key.replace(/[(ч)|(д)|(м)|(с)]/g, 'h, d, m, s');`

Не работает, оставляет всё на своих местах, подозреваю что это из-за строки замены `('h, d, m, s')`.

Можно ли изменить значение каждой отдельной скобочной группы?

Comment: А как выглядит `key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В отличие от PHP и его [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-replace.php), где можно указать двумя массивами *что* менять *на что*, в JavaScript похожей механики нет. Подробнее про метод JavaScript [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) (на англ.)

**Обновил** ответ: во-первых, незачем там регулярные выражения использовать, можно просто `.replace('д','d')`. Во-вторых, короче получается с объектом замен:

```
var key, R, from;
key = '3 д 12 ч 13 м 50с';
R = {'д':'d', 'ч':'h', 'м':'m', 'с':'s'}; // что на что менять
for( from in R) key = key.replace( from, R[ from]);
// 3 d 12 h 13 m 50s
```

Comment: Почитал про str_replace в php, такого поведения я и ожил от js, жаль конеш

Comment: @ArtemS. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Регулярное выражение `[(ч)|(д)|(м)|(с)]` находит 1 символ: `(`, `ч`, `)`, `|`, `д`, `м` или `с` столько раз, сколько встречается во входной строке, т.к. в шаблоне используется символьный класс (`[...]`). Причем эти символы могут быть частями другого слова.

Я полагаю, эти буквы находятся после чисел. Тогда подойдет следующий код:

```js
var re = /(\d+\s*)([чдмс])/g; 
var map = {'д':'d', 'ч':'h', 'м':'m', 'с':'s'}; 
var str = '*12д-1ч+3м-57с';
var result = str.replace(re, function(m, $1, $2) {
     return $1 + map[$2];
});
document.write(result);
```

Если "чдмс" являются отдельными "словами", можно использовать `\b` в конце (граница слова): `/(\d+\s*)([чдмс])\b/g`.

Comment: [(ч)|(д)|(м)|(с)] - понял, что ерунду написал, насчёт формата key, вы правильно поняли, только они складываются и вычитаются друг с другном(*-1ч+3м)

Comment: Тогда я предлагаю совместить сопоставления с регулярным выражением. Конечно, если нет нужды проверять контекст, решение Сергикса подходит лучше. Если же необходимо сверять контекст, моё решение имеет преимущество.